# SimpleForm version of :scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

`form_for` Rails helper has the `:scope` option that sets the param name option. Is there a SimpleForm equivalent for this?

Comment: It should be exactly the same as `form_for` as its just a wrapper. See https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/0cf25f8aa42bf444b72db38dcb72397c5d108b5a/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb#L14

Comment: Also `form_for` does not appear to have a `scope` option [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for); however `form_with` does [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with). That being said it looks like you can pass an `as` option to `form_for` to change the param grouping so `simple_form_for @user, as: :client` should work